# Detect page loaded with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a portfolio page filled with images that I would like to hide with a mask overlay until all the images have had a chance to finish loading. Is there a way to detect loading finished for all the content on a page?

I would like to find a way to do this, preferably using the jQuery library. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't. Seriously. People are used to pages loading incrementally. Showing them a loading screen until the entire page is ready is just going to increase the number of people who get bored and go away before the loading has finished.

Comment: Not my call, thanks for the opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the images you want to have finished loading before the overlay is removed all have the class `.theImagesToLoad`:

```
// count the number of images
var imageCount = $(".theImagesToLoad").length;

// init a load counter
var loadCounter = 0;
$(".theImagesToLoad").load(function() {

    // an image has loaded, increment load counter
    loadCounter++;

    // remove overlay once all images have loaded
    if(loadCounter == imageCount) {
        removeOverlay();
    }
}).each(function() {

    // make sure the `.load` event triggers
    // even when the image(s) have been cached
    // to ensure that the overlay is removed
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

See:
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `window.onload` event, it gets fired when all images have been loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('#maskoverlay').remove();
}
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

Comment: So this will detect for 100% image loading?

Comment: Yes, but it gets fired when all the html elements have loaded, which is a later than the `document.load` event.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery ready event fires when the DOM is ready not when all the images are loaded. You can use the window.onload as suggested before or if you want to use jQuery you can use the load event like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For document ready use:

```
$(function(){

   // Your code

});
```

However, you'll have to load the mask in CSS with the page and then use the above function to remove it. You won't be able to create the mask in javascript before all the images have loaded unless you again use javascript to supress the images loading, create your mask, load the images, then remove the mask

Comment: The question is asking for when the images have finished loading. document.ready is when the DOM is finished which is usually before images have finished loading. The point of `ready` is so that you don't have to wait for the images.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry might have misunderstood you, 
this plugin might help you:

https://gist.github.com/268257

Comment: The question is asking for when the images have finished loading. document.ready is when the DOM is finished which is usually before images have finished loading. The point of ready is so that you don't have to wait for the images.

Comment: And "WHAT" or you can use that?

Comment: nope .. i guess that will execute after `<img src='somesource.jpg' />` is printed but it does not determine if image has been loaded or not. Only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use the onload event for the `<body>` tag and attach to a function

or you can user the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like ?

```
$(function() {
    var img = [];
    var imgarr = ["image1.png","image2.png", ....];
    var imgcount = 0;

    var loadTimer;
    loadTimer = setInterval(function() {
        if(imgcount == imgarr.length){
           clearInterval(loadTimer);

           // ALL IMAGES ARE DONE LOADING HERE
           //   use : $(img) to have a JQuery object of the image elements
        }
    },100);

    $(imageContainer).hide();
    for(var i=0;i<imgarr.length;i++){
        img[i] = new Image();
        img.style.display = 'none';
        $(img[i]).appendTo(imageContainer);
        img[i].src = imgarr[i];
        img[i].onload = function() { imgcount++; }
    }
});
```